# One-loop triangle integral with equal masses

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

This is a question about the explicit form for an integral that is very common in QFT.

[image]

$$I_3(p,p';\,m,d)\equiv \int \frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{\left(k^2+m^2\right)\left((k+p)^2+m^2\right)\left((k+p')^2+m^2\right)}$$
I'm doing this with Euclidean momentum and all the external momentum are off-shell.

If I use Feynman parameters (or Schwinger parameters after a few steps) I get the following integral
$$\frac{\Gamma(3-\frac{d}{2})}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\int dx\,dy\,dz \,\delta(x+y+z-1)\left[m^2+x(1-x)p^2+y(1-y)p'^2-2xy\,p\cdot p'\right]^{\frac{d}{2}-3}.$$

My question is now whether this can be put in terms of special functions such as hypergeometric functions. This is possible for the bubble integral which involves two propagators rather than three, and the expression is very useful. I find it hard to believe that this hasn't been done for this integral but I can't seem to find results anywhere. Mathematica has been stuck on it for over an hour, and if it does eventually spit out a result typically it won't be in the nicest form.

How to do this integral?

---

Just a clarification, I'm interested in the case where the dimension $d$ is arbitrary (and if anything mostly interested in $d=2$). For the corresponding bubble integral where there is no $p'$ or third propagator we get a relatively simple formula like
$$I_2(p; m,d)=\frac{\Gamma\left(2-\frac{d}{2}\right)}{(4\pi)^{d/2}m^{4-d}}\,\,{}_2 F_1\left(1,2-\frac{d}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{p^2}{4m^2}\right).$$

This isn't hard to derive but I've never actually seen this formula in print (if I did I'd probably find the triangle integral there too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of integral can be decomposed into so called [Spence functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function). In general these expressions get quite "messy" because you really need to dig into the pole/branch cut structure of the integrand. For a discussion of the matter at hand see e.g. "Scalar One-Loop Integrals" by t'Hooft and Veltman [tH], which is basically a classic resource for the discussion of these integrals. Furthermore you find explicit formulas in terms of [Dilogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm) in "Techniques for the calculation of electroweak radiative corrections at the one-loop level and results for W-physics at LEP200" by Ansgar Denner [De].

- [tH] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321379906059
- [De] https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1075.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any results for arbitrary dimension? I'm actually mostly interested in $d=2$ if anything (certainly not $d=4$). I had ran across t'Hooft and Veltman's paper before and thought maybe I could try to adapt their tricks but it looked like a mess, so I thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: I actually do not know what the state of the art loop computation in $D=2$ is doing. But since the one-point integral is actually finite in this case there might be procedures different from the one in $D=4$. But basically you should be able to perform the calculation in $D$-dimension in full analogy as in [tH] and check the two dimensional case.

Comment: By the way, I did find a paper (Berg, Nuovo Cimento A (1977), 58) that explains how to do one-loop diagrams with arbitrary number of propagators in d=2. You can reduce everything to a sum over bubble integrals so it ends up being much nicer than d=4.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can take a look to
https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0509233.pdf
seems to have some expression for d=2 and other dimensions
also in
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.09442.pdf

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.